# Using cboden/ratchet I got Interface 'Rachet\MessageComponentInterface' not found error

Tags: laravel-5, socket.io, ratchet

In my laravel 5.7 app I installed cboden/ratchet using some online docs

```
composer.json :
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        ...
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.1",
```

With app/Classes/Socket/Base/BaseSocket.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes\Socket\Base;

use Rachet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Rachet\ConnectionInterface;

class BaseSocket implements MessageComponentInterface {

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $mgs) {

    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {

    }

}
```

and console command app/Console/Commands/ChatServer.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use App\Classes\Socket\ChatSocket;

class ChatServer extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'chat_server:serve';

    protected $description = 'chat_server description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info("Start server!");
        $server= IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new ChatSocket()
                )
            ),
            8080
        );

        $server->run();
    }
}
```

But running command in console I got error:

```
$ php artisan chat_server:serve
Start server!
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Rachet\MessageComponentInterface' not found in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/app/Classes/Socket/Base/BaseSocket.php on line 7

   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Interface 'Rachet\MessageComponentInterface' not found

  at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/app/Classes/Socket/Base/BaseSocket.php:7
     3| 
     4| use Rachet\MessageComponentInterface;
     5| use Rachet\ConnectionInterface;
     6| 
  >  7| class BaseSocket implements MessageComponentInterface {
     8| 
     9|     public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    10| 
    11|     }


   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Interface 'Rachet\MessageComponentInterface' not found

  at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/app/Classes/Socket/Base/BaseSocket.php:7
     3| 
     4| use Rachet\MessageComponentInterface;
     5| use Rachet\ConnectionInterface;
     6| 
  >  7| class BaseSocket implements MessageComponentInterface {
     8| 
     9|     public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    10| 
    11|     }
```

Did I miss some declarations or have I to add declarations to app.php ?
Reading docs I missed if I have add config declarations?

**UPDATED BLOCK # 2:**

Searching for decision I found an opinion, that I need to create my own service provider for it register it properly in Laravel
Which steps have I to do to create my own service provider for "cboden/ratchet" ? This is out of my laravel expierence...

Thanks!

Comment: Please look at UPDATED BLOCK # 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like misspelling. Must be :

```
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
```